# Use of the word 'lower'

Tags: grammar

When we turn the volume up and down by a remote of an air con, it is something reverse you see... we turn the volume up, it lowers the temperature of air con but of the room it increases... and vice a verse. So, what should we say when we want more cooling?

> Lower the temperate.

OR

> Turn air con volume up.

Comment: Maybe it’s regional, but I never hear “air con” where I live in the US. It’s either “air conditioner,” or “A/C” for short.

Answer (score 5):

I would usually say:

> Turn the air conditioner up.

Although I might say instead:

> Turn the thermostat down.

In the situation you describe, I doubt I would ever say:

> Lower the temperature. (and definitely not “Lower the *temperate*” – was that a typo?)

Although I might say:

> Can we make it a little cooler in here?